# Automation : After file upload in phantomJS (Headless) browser through selenium, Processing Pop-up remain on screen for infinite seconds

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, phantomjs

In my c# code I am performing a file upload action through phantomJS browser.

```
public void ImportFileNew(String importType, String fileNamePath)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        switch (importType)
        {
            case "Currency Rates":
                ((OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver)_driver).ExecutePhantomJS("var page = this; page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', '"+fileNamePath+"');");
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(importType + "Name is not correct please check in options");
        }
    }
```

**Note**: This code is working fine. But issue is after uploading file a processing pop-up comes for infinite seconds. If I run the script for other browser like chrome, then pop-up appears for fraction of seconds and then go.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After digging on to this I found that there is some issue in PhantomJs in file uploading scenario. Refer this link:
[PhantomJS issue | File Upload](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506)

I think presently there is no any concrete solution/workaround on this present. So I am marking it closed for now.